# Ubuntu lags on my laptop

Tags: nvidia, gnome, ssd, hp

I need some help. I installed few months ago Ubuntu on my Laptop, an HP 15-CS1022NL with this specs:

> Intel i7 8th Gen
>
> 16GB RAM
>
> 512GB SSD
>
> Nvidia GeForce GTX 1050

Since first installation (Ubuntu 18.04 to now Ubuntu 19.10) I have problems. The system seems to lag in simple operation such as scrolling, navigate on web and so on. It doesn't happen anytime. Sometimes I start up my PC and it have no problems, no lags and everythings works fine. I have no idea why this happens.

Another thing to share with you is: Ubuntu is installed on SSD in Dual Boot with Windows (I don't know if it is important) and I noticed, maybe, the lag seems to appear after wake up from system suspend or lid is closed and re-opened.

Can you help me? Can I check if something isn't working fine?

I can share with you more information if needed. Thanks.

Edit 1:

```
free -h

total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:         15Gi       1,5Gi        11Gi       312Mi       2,6Gi        13Gi
Swap:       3,8Gi          0B       3,8Gi
```

```
sysctl vm.swappiness

vm.swappiness = 60
```

```
dpkg -l *nvidia* | grep ii

ii  libnvidia-cfg1-435:amd64         435.21-0ubuntu2 amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX configuration library
ii  libnvidia-common-430             430.50-0ubuntu2 all          Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
ii  libnvidia-common-435             435.21-0ubuntu2 all          Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
ii  libnvidia-compute-435:amd64      435.21-0ubuntu2 amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-compute-435:i386       435.21-0ubuntu2 i386         NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-decode-435:amd64       435.21-0ubuntu2 amd64        NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-decode-435:i386        435.21-0ubuntu2 i386         NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-encode-435:amd64       435.21-0ubuntu2 amd64        NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-encode-435:i386        435.21-0ubuntu2 i386         NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-435:amd64         435.21-0ubuntu2 amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-435:i386          435.21-0ubuntu2 i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-gl-435:amd64           435.21-0ubuntu2 amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-gl-435:i386            435.21-0ubuntu2 i386         NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-435:amd64         435.21-0ubuntu2 amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-435:i386          435.21-0ubuntu2 i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
ii  nvidia-compute-utils-435         435.21-0ubuntu2 amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
ii  nvidia-dkms-435                  435.21-0ubuntu2 amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
ii  nvidia-driver-435                435.21-0ubuntu2 amd64        NVIDIA driver metapackage
ii  nvidia-kernel-common-435         435.21-0ubuntu2 amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
ii  nvidia-kernel-source-435         435.21-0ubuntu2 amd64        NVIDIA kernel source package
ii  nvidia-prime                     0.8.13          all          Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                  435.21-0ubuntu2 amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
ii  nvidia-utils-435                 435.21-0ubuntu2 amd64        NVIDIA driver support binaries
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-435    435.21-0ubuntu2 amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver
```

I don't know if my SSD firmware is current. Can I check it?

```
sudo dmidecode -s bios-version

F.08
```

Edit 2:

```
sudo blkid

/dev/nvme0n1p5: UUID="f14e8c9f-195b-4311-8c05-2c78ff9fe41f" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="fa0c46ba-60d4-430c-a304-a2d5e87ba963"
/dev/nvme0n1p6: UUID="741f2223-7c95-4527-bf53-d57d98623914" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="eab21086-c1fe-43be-87ba-699ddff72743"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop7: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/nvme0n1p1: LABEL="SYSTEM" UUID="3E98-4934" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="3a3bb770-f12d-4e69-9155-4c8870fe9024"
/dev/nvme0n1p3: LABEL="Windows" UUID="E8A6AAE9A6AAB808" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="96ef921f-e645-4b3a-a843-92125ddb3dbe"
/dev/nvme0n1p4: LABEL="Windows RE tools" UUID="0EE83CEDE83CD4A5" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="6dbe4e81-bcce-4f09-aff6-2e37a2668697"
/dev/nvme0n1p7: UUID="eeaa5a2b-c724-4bef-96b4-76940b098ba4" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="6f3dda6d-f838-4091-a15d-fcc073049d78"
/dev/loop8: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop9: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop10: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop11: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop12: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/nvme0n1p2: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="735fe8bb-bc65-44e6-8dc4-e529a78981a5"
```

```
cat /etc/fstab

# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p6 during installation
UUID=741f2223-7c95-4527-bf53-d57d98623914 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=3E98-4934  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# /home was on /dev/nvme0n1p7 during installation
UUID=eeaa5a2b-c724-4bef-96b4-76940b098ba4 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/nvme0n1p5 during installation
UUID=f14e8c9f-195b-4311-8c05-2c78ff9fe41f none            swap    sw              0       0
```

```
cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume
```

This file doesn't exist.

Edit 3:

```
sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=10
```

This doesn't work.

From the `top` command I noticed there are many processes with high CPU usage:

- **Xorg**: when I use application such as Firefox and IntelliJ and I scroll rapidly (with intent) the screen, it has freezes for 1 or 2 second, I can see from top command a 80% on average (up to 100%) usage of CPU of Xorg.
- **Web Content**: many times when using Firefox it appears with 70% (on average) usage of CPU.

Can be this the problem?

Edit 4:

```
ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions

totale 12
drwxr-xr-x 3 framan framan 4096 feb  3 16:18 .
drwx------ 3 framan framan 4096 feb 13 19:49 ..
drwxr-xr-x 5 framan framan 4096 feb  3 16:18 dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com
```

Instead of `free -h` I used `watch -n .5 free -h`. When the system lags it is the same, like this:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           15Gi       1,4Gi        12Gi       255Mi       1,7Gi        13Gi
Swap:         3,8Gi          0B       3,8Gi
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness`. Also, are your Nvidia drivers up to date (`dpkg -l *nvidia* | grep ii`)? Is the firmware in your SSD current? How about your BIOS (`sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`)?

Comment: @heynnema Just edited.

Comment: Thanks for the info. It looks ok. To check for the BIOS update, the HP web site needs the serial # of the laptop, so either check it yourself, or tell me the serial # and I'll try and find it.

Comment: To check the firmware on the SSD, type `sudo smartctl -i /dev/sda`, changing the sda if required.

Comment: Current Nvidia driver for your card is 440.59. Get it at https://www.geforce.com/drivers

Comment: I've just updated the BIOS and SSD firmware (already latest version). For the video card I tried to install the 440.59 but the installer said it is better to install suggested drivers from my distro and not from nvidia-installer.

Comment: This time when I turn on my laptop Ubuntu worked fine, but after closed e opened the lid (and logged), as already mentioned in question, now it lags...

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo blkid` and `cat /etc/fstab` and `cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`.

Comment: Just edited. Anyway thanks for your time @heynnema.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't resolve my problem, because I didn't find out the cause.

But I now installed Ubuntu 18.04 and it seems to have no problems with lag.

EDIT 1

Since few days the lag also appears with Ubuntu 18.04. Sometimes there is and sometimes not.